# drag and drop using post/sendmessage

Tags: c#

I am trying to find a way to preform drag and drop using API function SendMessage() or PostMessage(), I am using the following code but its not working:

```
API.Click(controlHandleStart, false, (ushort)RelativePointStart.X, (ushort)RelativePointStart.Y);//mouse down

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);

API.Click(controlHandleEnd, true, (ushort)RelativePointEnd.X, (ushort)RelativePointEnd.Y);//mouse up
```

Basically what I am trying to do is to preform a drag and drop for an email in outlook I want to drag an email and drop it into a folder within outlook but i need to use post/sendmessage.

I just sending the mouse down on the drag location and then I send the mouse up on the drop location, I am not able to find way to send the mouse move message.

Comment: Use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook namespace.

Comment: I totally agree with Hans. But if you really need to do this, try the SendInput API instead of generating window messages.

Comment: Thanks all. I need to use windows messages because I am creating an application that uses low level messages, I managed to send mouse clicks and keyboard key press, but I am not able to preform drag and drop or composite key strokes